# how to save multiple select data into a different table - pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, pivot-table

I have the input form as shown below[image]

data on health facilities(fasilitas keselamatan), safety facilities(fasilitas kesejahteraan) taken from a different table. And then the contents of the form
 in store in another table inside there is id corporation and id safeties, this is pivot table 
[image]

how to function store on its controller?

Comment: i dont know if i could help but your question is not clear to me .....  please correct if there is any space to change or edit to make clear

Comment: Are you trying to save data on the pivot table or through it to another table?